# Extract Partial Data from multiple excel sheets in the same workbook using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel Workbook with more than 200 sheets of data. Sheet names are as shown in the figure. I would like to assign each sheet to an individual variable as a data frame and later extract some required data from each sheet. Extracted information from all the sheet needs to be stored into a single excel sheet  As I cannot keep writing 200 times, I would like to know if I can write any function or use for loop to kind of automate this process.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\RECL\\Documents\\PRADYUMNA\\Experiment Data\\CNN\\CCCV Data.xlsx", sheet_name=5)
df2 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\RECL\\Documents\\PRADYUMNA\\Experiment Data\\CNN\\CCCV Data.xlsx", sheet_name=10)
df3 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\RECL\\Documents\\PRADYUMNA\\Experiment Data\\CNN\\CCCV Data.xlsx", sheet_name=15)

df1 = df1[0::100]
df2 = df2[0::200]
df3 = df3[0::300]
df1
```

```
i=0
for i in range(0,1035), i+5 :
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet_name=i)
df
```

I tried something like this but isn't working. Please let me know if there is any simple way to do it.

Thank you :)

Comment: Why not make a dict? `excels = {i: pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet_name=i) for i in input.sheet_names}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but an easier way to traverse through the sheet names would be with a for-each loop:

```
 for sheet in input.sheet_names:
```

Now you can do something for all the sheets no matter their name.

Regarding " would like to assign each sheet to an individual variable" you could use a dictionary:

```
sheets = {}
for sheet in input.sheet_names:
    sheets[sheet] = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet)
```

Now to get a sheet from the dictionary sheets:

```
sheets.get("15")
```

Or to traverse all the sheets:

```
for sheet in sheets:
    %do_something eg.%
    print(sheet)
```

This will print the data for each sheet in sheets.

Hope this helps / brings you further

Comment: Thank you so much @Wyrtz. Really helped me a lot.  Cheers :)